# Regression coefficients without intercept

Tags: regression, references, intercept

Could someone recommend a link or help me out here: where can I find the formula for the regression without an intercept, and how is it deriveed differently than the formula with the intercept? (matrix form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same formula you use in regression with an intercept: $\hat{\beta}=\left(X^TX\right)^{-1}X^Ty$. Just make sure there isn't a column of ones for the intercept. It's the same derivation as the formula with an intercept.

Here's a link to some notes that derive regression coefficients: [Statistics 512: Applied Linear Models - Chapter 5: Linear Regression in Matrix Form](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~boli/stat512/lectures/topic3.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind me asking another question - if I'm looking to compare variances of the same regression with and without an intercept by looking at their ratio, is there a difference in formulas?

Comment: Yup. The model without an intercept is actually a special case (nested) of the model with an intercept. Without the intercept, we are actually assuming the intercept is zero.

Comment: But if I need to take a ratio of variances, doesn't that mean their formula will just be the same?

Comment: The residual sums of squares will not be the same unless the regression model with an intercept fits the intercept to zero.

Comment: I apologize. I think I read your initial comment incorrectly. The standard F Test for choosing between two models, one of which is nested in the other, is valid. It's no different because you aren't including an intercept.

Comment: The pdf link was broken. I've updated it. Please check if the update link points to the same resources you intended it to.